# inverting text search while I type letters in dynamic search

Tags: ms-access, search, ado

I have MS Access form to do advanced search, when I type "marie" to search in OnChange textbox search my letters are inverted.
I am sure my code is right.

```
 Dim strSQL1, TestArray() As String
 Dim i As Integer

       Me.Text32 = Me.Tsearch.Text

            TestArray() = Split(Me.Text32, " ")
            For i = LBound(TestArray) To UBound(TestArray)                
                If TestArray(i) <> "" Then                    
                    arrayVal1 = arrayVal1 & "  telefone.job  like '%" & TestArray(i) & "%'" & " And"
     Me.TsearchX = Mid(arrayVal1, 1, Len(arrayVal1) - 3)             
    strSQL1 = "SELECT Top 10 * FROM telefone Where" & Me.TsearchX & " ORDER BY telefone.id desc
                 End If
              Next i
                  Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset
                      With rst1
                        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
                        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
                        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
                        .Open strSQL1, cnAccess, adCmdText
                      End With
         Set Me.Query_subform.Form.Recordset = rst1
```

I expect when I type letter they are showed right not inverse.
My sample is here. Please take a look and if possible guide me
[ado advanced search](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H5qe5WAwWvT1apYieGN0kZBmI6Fi8zTu)

Comment: I can't open rar file. What exactly does that file contain? All info should be provided as text in question. Show example of input, desired result, actual result. Edit question. I tested code and output looks right to me.

Comment: Also, image should be embedded in question, not a clickable link to a file that has to be downloaded.

Comment: excuse me. please look this acdb file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsolPGqAsa-CqLvaM2SFQbLL54vra80k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking at db. Typed letters display from left to right and output is also left to right. "Marie" outputs as "Marie" What do you want?

Comment: it may be related to my windows. when type marie output is eiram. because after typing m my cursor goes to right of m and a is typed before m: instead ma is am

Comment: Possibly, maybe as well as settings for right-to-left behavior, which my db seems to ignore. I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: if we make inactive loop part (for i ... next i) it does not occur. I think we need to edit it but what?

Comment: Also if we set recodrset to a listbox every things is OK. what defrence is between two controls?

Comment: Original code sets recordset of a form. A listbox is certainly very different from a form. But I don't know why that would make a difference with order of characters output. Again, since I don't get the issue, I can't advise how to fix.